# Where is the Tasks window in Visual Studio for Mac 2022?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-2022

This morning I installed the 2022 edition of Visual Studio for Mac (17.0) and was surprised to see the 'Tasks' pane was gone. That scans your solution for comments with `TODO` or `FIXME` in them. This is a screenshot from VS 2019, the pane is at the bottom and if it's not visible, you can reveal it from the View menu.

[image]

However, that option is not available in the newest Visual Studio, not even under Other Windows or Debug Windows:

[image]

It *is* available in the newest Visual Studio for Windows (though it's called Task List, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>). How can I restore this feature on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @VsMs mentioned, a new release (17.3) has fixed this problem and the Tasks window is now available:

[image]

Sorting (on description, file or path) still isn't working, but that's another good reason to keep this list small ...

Answer (score 1):

At this point, there is - **UNFORTUNATELY** - no Task-Window available.

Check out the Known Issus - [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/mac-release-notes#known-issues-), @glorfindl there might be a release in the pipeline: [check](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Tasks-Window-is-missing-in-VS-for-Mac-20/10054872)

Answer (score 0):

It's entirely possible that I'm overlooking something, but this is what I'm using now as a workaround: use the Find in Files option (<kbd>⇧</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>), check 'Use regular expressions' and enter something like `(FIXME|TODO|NICETOHAVE)`:

[image]

The `NICETOHAVE` wasn't included in Tasks but it's something I picked up from Eclipse / Java. It's certainly possible to make a more sophisticated regex which checks if it's inside a single-line comment, but for now it works ... sort-of:

- You can't sort the search results on code
- If the comment is preceded by actual code on the same line, you see that code as well
- If you open a new solution, Find in Files still looks in the previously opened solution (but I'm sure further updates will fix this bug)